# How do you use Django URL namespaces?

Tags: django, django-urls

I'm trying to get the hang of [Django URL namespaces](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#defining-url-namespaces). But I can't find any examples or documentation.

Here is what I have tried.

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^foo/', include('sub_urls', namespace='foo', app_name='foo')),
    (r'^bar/', include('sub_urls', namespace='bar', app_name='bar')),            
)
```

sub_urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, url
from views import view1

urlpatterns = patterns('views',
    url(r'^(?P<view_id>\d+)/$', view1, name='view1')
)
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def view1(request, view_id):
    return render_to_response('view1.html', locals())
```

In view1.html, {% url foo:view1 3 %} outputs /foo/3, and {% url bar:view1 3 %} outputs /bar/3. This holds true whether I browse to /foo/X or /bar/X.

What I want is to be able to browse to /foo/X or /bar/X, and have {% url view1 3 %} output either /foo/3 or /bar/3, respectively.

Comment: The reason that I'm doing this is so that I can have the two namespaces use different CSS files. I.e. browsing under /foo would include foo.css, and /bar would include bar.css.

Comment: I would be aware that having different urls with the same content will definitely get your site penalized on search engines. I don't know if that is a concern for you or not, but if it is, I would recommend working around this some other way. Perhaps you could set a cookie on the client and let them choose css styles in some other manner.

Comment: I ended up setting the CSS based on different sub-domains. It's just a pain to test locally, which required hostfile entries.

Comment: Note that namespaces are made for _disambiguation_: Refer to a specific view _object_ even if view _names_ clash (and doing so by means of a namespace prefix). What you are asking for above could be considered _'ambiguation'_: using a single view name to refer to either of two different view objects on purpose, depending on context. Mixing these two goals does not sound pythonic to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that this isn't possible in django right now. Have a look at this [message board post](http://www.mail-archive.com/django-users@googlegroups.com/msg84002.html) which references [Ticket 11559](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11559). I think that you're trying to do the same thing - effectively pass an implicit parameter to the URL tag.

Also, assuming that `sub_urls` is from the same app both times you should make sure `app_name` is the same in both cases. You should only need to change namespace.

Answer (score 6):

There seems to be no direct way to do it. I would use a similiar solution as you introduced using a template tag, though I found a more generic way. I used the fact that you can pass optional parameters in your url conf, so you can keep track of the namespace:

```
#urls.py
from django.conf.urls import defaults

urlpatterns = defaults.patterns('',
    defaults.url(r'^foo/', include('sub_urls', namespace='foo', app_name='myapp'), 
    kwargs={'namespace':'foo'}),
    defaults.url(r'^bar/', include('sub_urls', namespace='bar', app_name='myapp'),
    kwargs={'namespace':'bar'}),      
)
```

That also violates the DRY principle, but not much though :)

Then in your view you get the namespace variable (sub_urls.py would be the same):

```
#views.py
from django import shortcuts

def myvew(request, namespace):
    context = dict(namespace=namespace)
    return shortcuts.render_to_response('mytemplate.html', context)
```

Later you just need a simple tag you pass your namespace variable and view name to:

```
#tags.py
from django import template
from django.core import urlresolvers

register = template.Library()

def namespace_url(namespace, view_name):
   return urlresolvers.reverse('%s:%s' % (namespace, view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)))
register.simple_tag(namespace_url)
```

and use it in the template (make sure to pass your view name as a string, and not as a template variable):

```
<!-- mytemplate.html -->
{% load tags %}
{% namespace_url namespace "view1"%}
```

Thanks for your hint btw.. I was looking for sth. like this.

Comment: I see that this is a very old post, however, dict(namespace=namespace) is computationally more expensive that {'namespace' : namespace}.  Use 'dis' to find out why!

Comment: Small change to namespace_url function:

    def namespace_url(namespace, view_name, *args, **kwargs):
        return urlresolvers.reverse('%s:%s' % (namespace, view_name), args=args, kwargs=kwargs)

Will allow you to support url parameters

Comment: Thx. Nice addition. Added it to the answer.

Comment: I think after adding the `kwargs`, one could and should remove the `namespace` and `app_name` parameters from the `include()` calls in the given case. Reasonably DRY again, then.

Answer (score 0):

I realize the solution below violates the DRY principal as you have to create essentially duplicate url config files for foo and bar, however I think it should work.

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^foo/', include('sub_urls_foo')),
    (r'^bar/', include('sub_urls_bar')),            
)
```

sub_urls_foo.py:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, url
from views import view1

urlpatterns = patterns('views',
    url(r'^(?P<view_id>\d+)/$', view1, 'view1_foo', {'namespace': 'view1_foo'})
)
```

sub_urls_bar.py:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, url
from views import view1

urlpatterns = patterns('views',
    url(r'^(?P<view_id>\d+)/$', view1, 'view1_bar', {'namespace': 'view1_bar'})
)
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def view1(request, view_id, namespace):
    return render_to_response('view1.html', locals())
```

And then for the template use this:

```
{% url namespace 3 %}
```

I haven't tested the idea of using a variable in the name section of the {% url %} tag, but I think it should work.

Comment: So you would need to use either {% url view1_bar 3 %} or {% url view1_foo 3 %}? What I really want is to be able to use {% url view1 3 %}, and have it pick foo or bar depending on which namespace matches the current URL.

Comment: Your right, my example will not work.  I built it under the assumption that I could pass a template variable to the {% url %} tag.  Which I have now read is not the case.  So that leaves you two options.  Either process the url in your view using reverse() and pass it in the context to template, or make a custom template tag.

Answer (score -1):

Here is one solution I came up with.

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext

def render_response_context(view, locals):
    request = locals["request"]
    app = "bar" if request.META["PATH_INFO"].lower().startswith("/bar") else "foo"
    return render_to_response(view, locals, 
        context_instance=RequestContext(request, current_app=app))

def view1(request, view_id):    
    return render_response_context('view1.html', locals())
```

view1.html:

```
{% load extras %}
{% namespace_url view1 3 %}
```

extras.py:

```
from django import template
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

register = template.Library()

@register.tag
def namespace_url(parser, token):
    tag_name, view_string, arg1 = token.split_contents()
    return NamespaceUrlNode(view_string, arg1)

class NamespaceUrlNode(template.Node):
    def __init__(self, view_string, arg1):
        self.view_string = view_string
        self.arg1 = arg1
    def render(self, context):
        return reverse("%s:%s" % (context.current_app, self.view_string), args=[self.arg1])
```

Basically I made sure to always pass the current_app context as either "foo" or "bar", which I calculate manually by looking at the request URL. Then I use a custom tag that resolves a URL based on current_app.

It's not very generic; "foo" and "bar" are hard-coded, and the tag can only take exactly one argument. Even with those issues fixed, this seems like a hack.