# Anyone knows good Django URL namespaces tutorial?

Tags: django, django-urls

I'm looking for a good tutorial for URL namespaces in Django. I find official documentation a little too sparse - it lacks good examples. I found [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919328/how-do-you-use-django-url-namespaces) here on stack, but the answers didn't help me to fully understand the subject either.

Comment: Did you check url dispatcer doc in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns I reccomend you to read the whole section, because if you understand the basics about how it works, then it would be easier to understand

Comment: @FallenAngel: my point still stays - in the official documentation there are no good examples of using namespaces.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Agreed, the docs for this are rather confusing. Here's my reading of it (NB: all code is *untested!*):

In `apps.help.urls`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', 'apps.help.views.index', name='index'),
    ]
```

In your main `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^help/', include('apps.help.urls', namespace='help', app_name='help')),
    url(r'^ineedhelp/', include('apps.help.urls', namespace='otherhelp', app_name='help')),
    ]
```

In your template:

```
{% url help:index %}
```

should produce the url `/help/`.

```
{% url otherhelp:index %}
```

should produce the url `/ineedhelp/`.

```
{% with current_app as 'otherhelp' %}
    {% url help:index %}
{% endwith %}
```

should likewise produce the url `/ineedhelp/`.

Similarly, `reverse('help:index')` should produce `/help/`.

`reverse('otherhelp:index')` should produce `/ineedhelp/`.

`reverse('help:index', current_app='otherhelp')` should likewise produce `/ineedhelp/`.

Like I said, this is based on my reading of the docs and my existing familiarity with how things tend to work in Django-land. I haven't taken the time to test this.

Comment: why do we need app_name and namespace both set? Was just wondering.
Seems it also works when not setting the app_name

Comment: Because the docs [led me to believe they were necessary](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/urls/#defining-url-namespaces). Even if the docs are wrong or misleading, it's probably more future-proof to include `app_name`, as documented, in case the behavior changes in the future to match the docs. If you truly want to know why, you'd have to read the code.

Comment: Good suggestion I normally try to read as much source as possible, but couldn't directly find the related part, will do some more digging. Read before a good article which said: The source never lies, but the manual may do. He basically told people to read the source if they encountered a problem or used the api wrong hehe.

Comment: Be carefull. Runs for me but without quotes: {% url help:index %}

Comment: Ack! I can never remember when I'm supposed to quote stuff or not in Django template tags. Good catch.

Answer (score 0):

This is from the docs

```
(r'^help/', include('apps.help.urls', namespace='foo', app_name='bar')),
```

Maybe you should be more specific about what you are trying to do.