# Django- URL namespace

Tags: python, django, web, django-urls

Can someone please explain to me the concept of URL namespace in Django.I did find a similar question([Anyone knows good Django URL namespaces tutorial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126489/anyone-knows-good-django-url-namespaces-tutorial)) but I still havent understood it.

Comment: Which part is unclear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine you have three apps in your project:

- reviews
- products
- users

For each app you have a view in your `views.py` called `DetailView`.

```
class DetailView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    # Some logic here.
```

To call the view, you have a URL in your `urls.py` that you've named `detail`. This could get confusing!

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail')
```

To distinguish between the URLs (for example, in your templates using `{% url ... %}`) you can use namespacing.

```
url(r'^api/v1/reviews/', include(reviews_urls, namespace="reviews"))
```

When you namespace your URLs, you can reference them in templates or redirects as `reviews:detail` which simplifies your life and makes code more reusable.

```
def my_view(request):
    ...
    return redirect('reviews:detail', foo='bar')
```